# Python: Applying common keys from one Dictionary to another

Tags: python, dictionary

I am fairly new to dictionaries, so this is probably a fairly basic question.

Let's say I have two different dictionaries with similar elements.
Example:

```
    Dictionary1 = {'Bob' : 1, 'Mary' : 2, 'Sue' : 3, 'George' : 4}
    Dictionary2 = {'Bob' : 1, 'Sue' : 2, 'Jill' : 3, 'Isaac' : 4, 'George' : 5}
```

I want to be able to take the intersection of the two dictionaries and apply the indices of the first dictionary to the second. So I want an output that looks something like this:

```
    DictionaryCombo = {'Bob' : 1, 'Sue' : 3, 'George' : 4}
```

Please excuse my formatting for my desired output, as I am not certain what it should look like, though I know that I want the key and value pairs of the intersection of the two dictionaries.

Comment: Please use actual Python syntax to show what your input dictionaries look like so we have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you clarify your question using actual Python syntax for dictionaries? Dictionaries don't have an order or natural index. Your `Keys1` cannot be a valid dict key because it's a mutable list. Using real Python syntax would clear this up.

Comment: Hmm... I edited the question, is that the proper syntax?

Comment: lol  nope ... that gets syntax error :P do you actually know what dictionaries are? or do you want lists of dictionaries? its confusing what you actually want

Comment: I'm pretty sure I want dictionaries, but I just started learning about them, and unfortunately, I've yet to find a decent tutorial for them.

Comment: Is the [official Python tutorial's chapter on dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) not enough?

Comment: I updated the question again. I think that the syntax is right this time. I think what is confusing me is that I have lists of data that I am trying to apply to dictionaries with specific keys. With this, I want to find the intersection of the two dictionaries so that I essentially have the same keys for a new dictionary that is to be defined as what exists in both dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to subset d1 so it only has elements present in d2

```
d1 = {'Bob': 1, 'Mary': 2, 'Sue': 3, 'George': 4}
d2 = {'Bob': 101, 'Sue': 102, 'Jill': 103, 'Isaac': 104, 'George': 105}
{k: v for k, v in d1.items() if k in d2}
# {'Bob': 1, 'Sue': 3, 'George': 4}
```

Or you mention *apply*, so did you want to update values in d2?

```
d2.update(d1)
print d2
# {'Sue': 3, 'Mary': 2, 'Jill': 103, 'Isaac': 104, 'Bob': 1, 'George': 4}
```

Or, if you really are starting with two lists (and not starting with dict's):

```
el1 = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Sue', 'George']
el2 = ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Jill', 'Isaac', 'George']
dict( (val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(d1, start=1) if val in set(el2) )
#{'Bob': 1, 'Sue': 3, 'George': 4}
```

If you have two lists, one of keys, and one of values, and wish to make them a `dict`, then you can use `zip`:

```
keys = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'Sue', 'George']  
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict( zip(keys, vals) )
# {'Bob': 1, 'Mary': 2, 'Sue': 3, 'George': 4}
```

Comment: Your most recent edit is moreso what I am looking for I believe. What if the values weren't exactly chronological like that though? Or what if the values really were just arbitrary numbers?

Comment: @user1620716 Given that scenario then, you'd want a name-> arbitrary value `dict` and you're back to the first posted example...

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, and it does help. But I do wonder if you could help with another minor problem. Is it possible to create a dictionary using already created lists? I have a list of "arbitrary numbers", as well as a list of dates. I would like them to be key value pairs. This is the part that I believe the Python tutorial is lacking for me.

Comment: Okay, dictionaries are amazing! Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: @user1620716 I've added that to the answer as it possibly would have been applicable on the first revision of your question

Answer (score 2):

`dict.viewkeys()` method provides a set-like object that allows easily to find common keys of two dictionaries (an intersection):

```
d1 = {'Bob' : 1, 'Mary' : 2, 'Sue' : 3, 'George' : 4}
d2 = {'Bob' : 1, 'Sue' : 2, 'Jill' : 3, 'Isaac' : 4, 'George' : 5}

common_keys = d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys()
dict_with_d1_values = {k: d1[k] for k in common_keys}
# -> {'Bob': 1, 'George': 4, 'Sue': 3}
```

Or if you actually need both values:

```
dict_with_combined_values = {k: (d1[k], d2[k]) for k in common_keys}
# -> {'Bob': (1, 1), 'George': (4, 5), 'Sue': (3, 2)}
```

Comment: These are really interesting features! Thank you for sharing them. :)